# Converting ASP.Net (c#) web application to Windows Service

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created on ASP.Net Web application (C#) in Visual Studio 2010. Now I want to convert this web application into Windows Service. I never work with windows service before. So can anybody help me?

Your help is really appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: A web application and a windows service are two very different things. You might need to better explain your applications and goal(s), as well as asking a more specific question than "can anybody help me."

Comment: What does your asp.net application do?

Answer (score 1):

Use [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/zt39148a.aspx) link as a walkthrough

You wont be able to 'convert it' as far as i'm aware, you will have to create a new windows service application and manually bring over the code that you require to put into the service. Only certain things will need to go in this service, like the functionality you wish to automate.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Nilam, you have given very little details about your web application, assuming you do not have a lot of UI (User Interface) logic, you could move the back-end / server side logic of your wb application to a windows service class or you could simply code your windows service in a way that it will consume/call the same class library your web application does, assuming you have isolated the business logic or application logic in a separated class library C# project in your current web application solution.

how do you expect the user to interact with the Windows Service, since a windows service has not user interface and why you want to do this conversion is not clear and cannot be answered unless you provide more details.

if your web application has no UI and it is only hosting XML web services or WCF services, the conversion will be easy because you can host WCF services in a Windows Service which does not run over / does not need IIS.

Comment: Thanks for your help and guidance. I am very new to windows service. I want same functionality in my windows service as it is in my asp.net web application. It haven't any UI.  I am briefing my web application here so according to that you can guide me how to do it.

Comment: 1. Retrieving very Big image from IMAGE folder which resides in my webapplication.  2.retrieve those big images and Resize those image according to certain condition and store it into database.  3.Retrive resize images stored in database and store it into server folder called Large and again resize that image in 3 more different size and save into their three respective size folders on server.   Now i wan t to build windows service with same functionality and it run on server after every 15 mins.Hope now i am more clear.   please help me in this regards. my web application code is working fine